# Is there any way to “analytically” compute the following conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, stochastic-differential-equations, jensen-inequality

Let me define the following SDE: $$\begin{cases}
dX_{t}=X_{t}dW_{t}\\
X_{0}=1
\end{cases},$$ where $W$ is an appropriate Wiener process. My question is how we can compute

$$f\left(z\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}>z\right)?$$

Is there any “analytic” solution? (If I find a solution where the $\varPhi$ standard normal distribution function appears, I will consider it “analytic”, or at least a very “nice” solution.)

It is not necessary to compute it with the $\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\}$  condition, I would be glad if at least I could compute $f\left(y\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}=y\right)$.

The condition is an $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ measurable event, therefore $f\left(z\right)$ and $f\left(y\right)$ are real functions (and not “random variables”).

It is easy to verify, that the SDE has the following solution:
$$X_{t}=\exp\left\{ W_{t}-\frac{1}{2}t\right\} ,$$
so $X_{t}\overset{d}{=}\exp\left\{ N\left(-\frac{1}{2}t,t\right)\right\}$, otherwise: $X_{t}$ is lognormal distributed.

My calculation is the following so far:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}>z\right) =\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\left(X_{2}-X_{1}+X_{1}\right)\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}>z\right)}=
 =\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\left(X_{2}-X_{1}\right)\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}>z\right)}=\ldots$$

I could calculate the denominator and the second term of the numerator. The problem is $X$ doesn't have independent increments, therefore $X_{2}-X_{1}$ and $\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }$ are not independent, so I can't factor the expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\left(X_{2}-X_{1}\right)\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)\neq\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}-X_{1}\right)\cdot\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right).$$
I know if they were uncorrelated, then it would be enough, but I don't think this is the case. I can't calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}>z\right)$ as
$$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}>z\right)=\mathbb{E}\left.\left(X_{2}-X_{1}+x\right)\right|_{x>z},$$
since $X_{2}-X_{1}$ is not independent from the condition.

I thought a lognormal “model” would yield a “nice” solution, but I don't know if there is any way to calculate the conditional expectation above analytically (and not with simulation).

I had another idea below. Because of the distribution of $X_{t}$, I can write the following:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}>z\right) =\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left\{ N\left(0,2\right)-1\right\} \mid\exp\left\{ N\left(0,1\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right\} >z\right).$$

For first glance, I thought it would have had the same result if I had calculated $$\mathbb{E}\left(N\left(0,2\right)-1\mid N\left(0,1\right)-\frac{1}{2}>\ln z\right)$$ before (and as a side note I could have calculated it, because the distribution behind the expression is a multidimensional normal distribution,) and then I wanted to take the exponential because the exponential function is a monotonic transformation. That's right, but because the Jensen inequality
$$\exp\left\{ \mathbb{E}\left(N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)\right)\right\} \leq\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left\{ N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)\right\} \right).$$

So it doesn't work either. Anyway, is there any case when
$$\exp\left\{ \mathbb{E}\left(\xi\right)\right\} =\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left\{ \xi\right\} \right),$$ where $\xi$ is a random variable?

Comment: I would use not the arithmetic difference, but the multiplicative one, $X_2=X_1·(X_2/X_1)=X_1e^{W_2-W_1-\frac12}$.

Comment: Good idea, I will try it...in this case the multiplicative differences of $X$ are independent. Am I right? I mean $X_{2}/X_{1}$ is independent from $X_{1}$ in this case. Right?

Comment: Yes, increments over disjoint (semi-open) intervals are independent.

Comment: Note that your stochastic process is a martingale, i.e. $$\mathsf E(X_t \vert X_s)=X_s$$ for all $t>s$. In particular, $$\mathsf E(X_2 \vert X_1)=X_1.$$

Comment: We thus also have, by definition of the conditional expectation, that $$\mathsf E(X_2\vert X_1>z)=\frac{\mathsf E(X_2 [X_1>z])}{\mathsf P(X_1>z)}= \frac{\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_2\vert X_1)[X_1>z])}{\mathsf P(X_1>z)}= \frac{\mathsf E(X_1[X_1>z])}{\mathsf P(X_1>z)} =\mathsf E(X_1\vert X_1>z).$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got the following result: $$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}>z\right) =\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}\cdot\frac{X_{2}}{X_{1}}\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}>z\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}\cdot\chi_{\left\{ X_{1}>z\right\} }\right)\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X_{2}}{X_{1}}\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}>z\right)}=\ldots$$

Comment: $$\ldots= \frac{\left(\int_{B}\exp\left\{ x-\frac{1}{2}\right\} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{ -\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\} dx\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left\{ x-\frac{1}{2}\right\} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{ -\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\} dx\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(N\left(0,1\right)>\ln z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=
= \frac{1-\varPhi\left(\ln z+\frac{1}{2}-1\right)}{1-\varPhi\left(\ln z+\frac{1}{2}\right)},$$ where $B\overset{\circ}{=}\left\{ x:x>\ln z+\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ .

Comment: Please compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Conditional_expectation and note that $\mathsf E(X_2/X_1)=1$.

Comment: They are the same...